# Intellij and local Tomee 7.0.1

Tags: debugging, intellij-idea, jmx, apache-tomee, tomee-7

I have instance of Tomee 7.0.1 on my local HDD with latest Intellij.
When starting server using configuration in Intellij, it randomly connects, most of time it won't.
Trying to manuly deploy war:exloped using button in Intellij cause message:

> Artifact xxx:war exploded: Server is not connected. Deploy is not available.

Configuration in Intellij doesn't have anything different that can be found in tutorials, etc.

I spend so much time searching for sollution of this problem, found many possible like:
 - `setenv.bat` overwrting env var
 - wrong env `JAVA_OPTS`
 - missing `JAVA_HOME`
 and probably others which now I can't remember.

None of this works.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

which version of idea is it? They had a bug when 7.x was released and you needed to customize the properties they passed to the deployer of tomee as well as tomee properties but it has been fixes in recent releases.

Comment: ULTIMATE 2016.2.5